# Transfer app to another developer when the app has a version waiting for upload?

Tags: ios

I inherited the development of an iOS app from another developer, who published the first version in the App Store. Now it's time to publish version 2. The client is no longer in touch with the previous developer, so I cannot get the original certificate.

As I understand it, the client can have the app transferred from the previous developer to me.  However, the client has already created the new version in iTunes Connect, and its status is "Waiting for Upload". According to Apple, this status prevents the app from being transferred.  The client has found out from Apple that he can either wait 30 days for the pending version to expire, or create a new app with a different name for the new version.  Neither of these scenarios is acceptable to him from a business perspective.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.